# Is phrase "wheeled his way somewhere" neutral?

Tags: political-correctness, irony

To put the things into perspective, I am no native speaker. I've learnt English in a variety of places, school being one of them.

My English tutor presented a phrase to descibe a movement of a person on a wheelchair:

> to wheel her/his way somewhere

The phrase struck me as ironic. To say for example *Bob wheeled his way into the shop* seemed to accent the disability needlessly. Is it ironic or completely neutral?

Comment: To emphasize the wheelchar used: "he wheeled his way into an elevator" for example. Instead of using the common "went", "entered", etc. Also, I may find it ironic due to the internet meme "one does not simply walk into Mordor" -> "one does not simply wheel his way into Mordor".

Comment: He didn't walk.  If you aren't going to be vague, you have to describe how he got there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I see no negative connotation in the phrase *wheeled his way*.  It is more descriptive than *made his way* but no less neutral.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this way of communicating is proper, but here goes.

I am not a native speaker. According to my non-native speaking English teacher the matter is as stated by previous posters - completely neutral.

However, during several visits in UK, while working in broadly put services industry, I've had the chance to ask a few people about this. Here I've received results 50/50. What seemed important, was one of my managers - trained to be "extra sensitive" about these matters - suggested it may be considered ironic due to political correctness, and more - elaborated on the fun history of "phrases to describe disabled people", as these changed throughout last 40 years.

Regardless, I'll accept the answer "neutral".